# How to classify homomorphisms from $\operatorname{PSL}(2,p)$ to $\operatorname{PGL}(n,2)$ when $2^n=p+1$?

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$I am looking to classify the homomorphisms from the group $\PSL(2,p)=\Aut(\mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{F}_p)$ to $\PGL(n,2)=\GL(n,2)=\Aut(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})$ when $p$ is a Mersenne prime, i.e. $2^n=p+1$.

There is a bijection $\mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/g(x)$ given by $k \mapsto x^\infty+x^k$ where $x^\infty=0$. Given a Möbius transformation $f$, define the homomorphism $T$ by $T_f(x^\infty+x^k)=x^{f(\infty)}+x^{f(k)}$.

When $n=3$, $p=7$, $T$ is an isomorphism (see [Brown and Loehr - Why is $\PSL(2, 7) \cong \GL(3, 2)$?](https://personal.math.vt.edu/brown/doc/PSL(2,7)_GL(3,2).pdf)). What is $\operatorname{im}(T)\subset \PGL(n,2)$?

Comment: I think this rarely happens. An element of order $p$ in ${\rm PGL}(n,2)$ is only conjugate to $n$ of its powers in this situation, while (for $p>3$) an element of order $p$ in the simple group ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ is conjugate to $\frac{p-1}{2}$ of its powers. But note that in this situation $n = \log_{2}(p+1)$ is smaller than $\frac{p-1}{2}$ for Mersenne primes $p > 7.$

Comment: What I mean is "for a Mersenne prime $p >7$ there is no such homomorphism", ie there is no embedding of ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ as a subgroup of ${\rm PGL}(n,2)$.

Comment: I’m confused. So you’re saying the map $T: PSL(2,p) \rightarrow PGL(n,2)$ is not a homomorphism of groups? Where does it fail? $PSL(2,p)$ is generated by reflections $r: k \mapsto -1/k$ and translations $t: k \mapsto k+1$, so surely $T_r$ and $T_t$ are permutations of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. $T_{f\circ h}=T_f \circ T_h$ because we’re composing functions in the exponent. $T_f$ is linear because it maps a basis element $x^i$ to a linear combination of basis elements. Are you saying $im(T)=\langle T_r, T_t \rangle$ is trivial, or that $im(T)=PGL(2,n)$? Like, are you saying the inclusion isn’t proper?

Comment: @JacksonWalters I don't see why $T_f$ is linear (and I certainly don't understand your short argument). For instance, why is $T_r$ linear? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I am saying (in the second comment particularly) that when $p>7$ is a Mersenne prime there is no faithful group homomorphism from ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ into ${\rm PGL}(n,2)$ where $p = 2^{n} - 1$.

Comment: @TomDeMedts Choose a basis $\{x^i\}_{0 \le i < n}$ for $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. $T_r(x^i)=x^{r(\infty)}+x^{r(i)}=x^{-1/\infty}+x^{-1/i}=1+x^{n-1/i}$, so $T_r$ maps a basis element to a linear combinations of basis elements.

Comment: @JacksonWalters Sorry, but I still disagree. *Any* map from a vector space to another vector space maps basis elements to a linear combination of basis elements, even if it is non-linear. In fact, looking at the reference by Brown and Loehr you provide, they do quite a bit of work to show linearity, so you can't expect a one-line proof. Even more: I checked this for $p=31$, with $g(x) = x^5 + x^2 + 1$, and it turns out to be false: $T_r$ is not linear. (If you want, I can write down more details in an answer.)

Comment: @TomDeMedts Good. Was going to check $p=31$ next: github.com/jacksonwalters/fano-plane-symmetries, where I start to compute the groups involved. sage's is_isomorphism isn't working for $n=3$, $p=7$, but I'm still curious about this map; it seems to be more than a bijection of sets between $\mathbb{F}_{2^n} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$; feels geometric. In Brown+Loehr, the Möbius transformations have a $c^2$in the denominator, and it's used as the quadratic residues mod $7$. are squares. I'd love to see a non-linearity proof. I'd like to manipulate HDD bits using Möbius transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $T \colon \mathrm{PSL}_2(p) \to \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{F}_{2^n}) \colon f \mapsto T_f$ does not have its image in $\mathrm{GL}_n(2)$ for other Mersenne primes $p = 2^n - 1$, unlike the case $p = 7 = 2^3 - 1$.

For instance, let $p = 31$ and consider $\mathbb{F}_{32} \cong \mathbb{F}_2[x] / (g)$ with $g(x) = x^5 + x^2 + 1$, as in the question, and let $f \colon \mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{F}_p) \to \mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{F}_p) \colon a \mapsto -a^{-1}$ (so $f \in \mathrm{PSL}_2(p)$). The map $T_f$ is then the permutation of $\mathbb{F}_{32}$ mapping each $x^k$ to $1 + x^{f(k)}$. In particular,
\begin{align*}
T_f(1) &= 1, \\
T_f(x^2) &= 1 + x^{15}, \\
T_f(x^5) &= 1 + x^{6}.
\end{align*}
However, $x^5 + x^2 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_{32}$, but
$$ T_f(x^5) + T_f(x^2) + T_f(1) = 1 + x^6 + x^{15} = 1 + x^2 + x^4 \neq 0 ,$$
so $T_f$ cannot be linear, i.e., it is not contained in $\mathrm{GL}_n(2)$.

Comment: Cool. I realized after you wrote it wasn't linear that I needed to check $T_f(x+y)=T_f(x)+T_f(y)$. It's clear that $T_f(\lambda x)= \lambda T_f(x)$ for $\lambda \in \{0,1\}$ since $T_f(0)=x^{f(\infty)}+x^{f(\infty)}=0$. Your counter-example settles it. I suppose the problem is $x^k+x^j$ cannot be simply rearranged to $x^l$ for some $l$ depending on $g, j, k$. It just so happens to work for $p=7$, $n=3$. I wonder though, how non-linear is this map? Perhaps $\langle T_r, T_t \rangle$ is not a group, but it is *some* algebraic object. Which one?

Comment: @JacksonWalters Of course, $\langle T_r, T_t \rangle$ is still a group, because it's a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})$. To answer the question about "how non-linear" the map $T$ is, you could try intersecting the image of $T$ with $\mathrm{GL}_n(2)$ and computing its index in $\operatorname{im}(T)$, but I'm not sure what sort of information you would hope to get out of this.

Comment: I think that takes care of the question: $im(T)$ is a non-linear group of permutations of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ when $n\ne 3$. One can compute the linear subgroup $im(T) \cap GL(n,2)$, but why? Really I’m content now that I can perform but manipulations with Möbius transformations, linearly or non-linearly.

Comment: Indeed my comments stand. There is no group homomorphism at all from PSL(2,p) into GL(n ,2) when p>7 is a prime with p+1 =2^n , except for the homomorphism sending everything to the identity.